# Is it possible to bring TFS history along when importing database scripts into a database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, database-project

I have individual object scripts for database under TFS source control. I'd like to move to Visual Studio database projects. It is easy enough to import the existing scripts into the new project, but I'd really love to bring the existing script along with the files.

Is that possible to do that as part of the script import process or via some post processing in TFS to remap history?

If the answer changes with TFS versions I may be able to come up the requisite version.

Comment: What do these scripts do or what is it about them you want to preserve? I think Ed Eliott did some work on his blog to pull scripts into a dacpac, but whether or not this is going to meet your needs depends on what those needs are.

Comment: @PeterSchott This is a mature database with years of source history in the scripts. I want to modernize the build and deployment processes using a database project. Ideally I would be able maintain the version/change history.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to map the project to your TFS history. You could look at exporting history and committing that as a big blob or perhaps the comments for the objects could be updated to point to the TFS history for more details. There might be some magic you could work behind the scenes to copy history, but I'm not sure what that would be. You should be able to do some form of history export at the very least, but not sure how you'd get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is impossible for you to import SQL Script together with TFS history into a database project.

Answer (score 1):

You can import existing scripts into a database project using Visual Studio 2012 or later with the SQL Server Data Tools feature installed.

VS supports importing one or multiple SQL scripts. Your scripts will be reinterpreted and new scripts will be created from them (one for each table, view, stored procedure, etc). For example, if you have a script with a CREATE TABLE statement and another script with ALTER TABLE which adds a column to the table, they will be combined into a single CREATE TABLE statement.

[Some notes from MSDN about importing scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh864423(v=vs.103).aspx#bkmk_import_source_script):

> All objects from the import source that do not already exist in the
>   project will be added, and all objects in the import source that do
>   already exist in the project will overwrite the object definition in
>   the project.
>
> **Note**
>
> There are two known bugs in this path that will be fixed in a future
>   release:
>
> - If table/column constraints are defined outside of the CREATE TABLE statement in the project’s table definition, import will overwrite the
>     table definition such that the constraint is inline. However, it will
>     leave the out of line constraint, resulting in duplicate constraints
>     in the project.
> - Any master keys or database encryption keys from your source script that already exist in the project will be duplicated on import. Remove
>     duplicates in order to build the project.

Comment: If the imported scripts are only used as source for constructing new scripts then I suppose the history cannot be maintained. Unless TFS allows file history to be "managed" in such a away that I can associate with original version history.